# Where can I find the commands linked to keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04

I recently switched to Ubuntu 22.04 and I like its new screenshot UI. What I want is to find the command that gets executed when I press the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key. I would like to know how I can see the commands that get executed for the custom combinations.

Please do feel free to ask for additional information about my needs. And pardon me if I said something silly as I am very new to this forum.

Comment: For PtrScr, it will again be some obscure `dbus-send` command that communicates with the shell and is documented nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

For your certain question about the screenshot function, since it trys rendering your desktop let's assume it's a **gnome-relative** execution. So I print "gnome" in a terminal and **double press** "tab" for hints, it shows a number of instructions below:

```
$ gnome-
gnome-autogen.sh              gnome-session
gnome-calculator              gnome-session-classic
...
gnome-power-statistics        gnome-www-browser
gnome-screenshot
```

Bingo, there we find gnome-screenshot which means it's a builtin. Let's assure for that:

```
$ which gnome-screenshot 
/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot
```

For additional ways to use gnome-screenshot, print:

```
$ gnome-screenshot --help
```

For more info about gnome-screenshot, print:

```
$ man gnome-screenshot
```

As for other commands , they may not all be relative to gnome though, the way to explore is similar.
Feel free to ask anything here, we're all glad to help you!

Comment: This is a fine answer for Ubuntu versions other than 22.04. `gnome-screenshot` isn't the tool that Ubuntu 22.04 uses for screenshots and it also doesn't come preinstalled by default.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog You are right, `gnome-screenshot` is a traditional one. Though it indeed installed at my Ubuntu22.04.by default.

Comment: Did you do a fresh install or an upgrade? Because I did a fresh install and `gnome-screenshot` isn't installed. It isn't listed on the [22.04 manifest file](http://www.releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) too.

Comment: Yes I upgraded from 20.04, meybe that's the reason.

Comment: Yup. That's it. Upgrading doesn't remove the software you had installed.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Really appreciate it.
So, what is the command for the default UI?

Comment: As I said - some obscure `dbus-send` command. Eager to find it myself. @FeiLuo better remove this - otherwise very nice - answer, because it indeed misses the point for the new screenshot tool in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find it too, to create another key binding using the custom keyboard shortcuts in the settings.

What worked for me is creating another keybinding using gsettings set command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings show-screenshot-ui "['<Shift><Super>s','Print']"
```

Hopefully it would be handful for others.

although it might not resolve the question, it may help anyone looking for something as close as this, as I found this question in my search for this answer.